# Image texture has no effect on particle size

Tags: texturing, particles

I'm using a texture image to set the individual sizes of 119,617 stars (from the Hipparcos catalogue). Trouble is that my image has no effect on the sizes at all. The image is a row of pixels with (r,g,b,a) values between 0 and 1, with 0 being smallest and 1 being largest. I checked the values in the variable used to create the image and they are correct (meaning that they are not just a constant color, which would otherwise explain the constant particle size).

I'm new to this type of modeling, so I imagine I'm forgetting to change a setting or that I'm not generating the image itself right (even though the calculated rgba values are right).

Below is a screenshot of the texture tab for the particle system texture. The X value is the same as the number of stars. I'm confused by the color buttons to the right of the X and Y fields, as they seem to generate texture images themselves—leaving me to wonder if Blender is using the black color corresponding to Blank or if it is still using my texture image (starSize.032).

You can see that the Size and Length options are both selected, meaning that the image texture should be affecting particle size (which is to say star size).

[image]

I generated the texture image itself with the Python code (gotten from another post):

```
sizeTexture = bpy.data.textures["Texture"]
bpy.ops.image.pack(as_png=True) # Pack image into Blender file
sizeTexture.image = starSizeTexture
```

'starSizeTexture' is the variable in which I stored the (r,g,b,a) values for my 119,617 pixels:

```
starSizeTexture.pixels = localSizePixelsNorm[:]
```

where 'localSizePixelsNorm' is the normalized version of 'localSizePixelsNorm', with the normalization (to constrain values between 0-1) is done as:

```
maxSize = max(localSizePixels) 
localSizePixelsNorm = localSizePixels
localSizePixelsNorm[:] = [x / maxSize for x in localSizePixels]
```

'localSizePixels' itself is calculated (for each star) as:

```
localSizePixels[columnOffset:columnOffset+3] = [D] * 4
```

where 'D' is the apparent diameter of the star, calculated from the luminosity of the star and its temperature (a function of its B-V index, but that is of little importance). I'll post that code if it turns out to matter, but I suspect it won't.

The 'starSizeTexture' variable I created using:

```
starSizeTexture = bpy.data.images.new('starSize',nStars,1)
```

with 'localSizePixels' created as a list:

localSizePixels = list(starSizeTexture.pixels[:])

I hope walking in reverse through my code doesn't just confuse you. Many thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction to fix this. I just want to use this generated image texture to set the sizes of the stars correctly. Thanks!

Comment: How do you map this texture onto emitter object? Static size usually requires UV unwrapping of emitter. But texture dimensions are very extreme and I wonder what is your mesh look like.

Comment: I... haven't done anything to map the texture image onto the emitter object. It would make sense to do so, but my mesh is unusual in that it has only (disconnected) vertices, each corresponding to a data point in the Hipparcos catalog. Not sure how I might map a texture onto such a mesh. I just added a mesh in the particle system tab and ran my python script to generate the image and apply it to the particle system texture. I do see that in the Mapping section of the Texture tab, "Point" is selected...

Comment: I think you should use one face per vertex location with emitting set to one particle per face. In this case you can use UV map.

Comment: I can try... though with the current image texture (a row of 119617 pixels, one for each star in Hipparcos), the faces would each have to map into a pixel (of the texture). With this many pixels, any continuous surface would no doubt self-intersect many times, so I'm wondering—can the faces be disconnected, (so that each is a small island centered on a vertex)? Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Yeah, you can disconnect faces. Important thing is to not scale them to zero in real geometry, but scale only UV islands of these faces to fit pixel values: keyboard S, then press 0(zero) in UV editor.

Comment: That will be a lot of adding and scaling faces ;-) Wondering if there is a way to iterate through the vertices with Python. This seems like something for a script!